# How can I make an image resize dynamically next to a floating sidebar?

Tags: html, image, css

How can I make the image fit into the available space left to the sidebar? But when it gets pushed down by additional content it should resize to its original size.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/5emOdkHN1dVHf7jOTZqD?p=preview

As you can see the image is 400px width, the space left to the sidebar div that floats right is just 300px. What I try to get done is that the image is displayed left from the sidebar and auto resizes to fit into this space. But if text is added above the image (this is for CMS) and the image gets pushed down below the sidebar, then it should resize again to fill the space it now has except it exceeds its original size.

```css
    .container {
      width: 600px;
      border: 1px solid #008000;
    }
    .main {
      border: 1px solid #800a0b;
    }
    .sidebar {
      width: 300px;
      float: right;
      border: 1px solid #303c80;
    }
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }
    img {
      width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://imsky.github.io/holder/holder.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>Aliquam faucibus vitae risus et tempus. Praesent ut ex at tortor congue condimentum. Praesent vel libero id augue ornare ultricies quis eu urna. Nulla et ornare risus. Duis volutpat, arcu a vulputate rhoncus, tortor leo lacinia turpis, sed cursus
          libero sapien quis neque. Curabitur dui nibh, convallis ut enim vitae, congue sollicitudin orci. Mauris pretium euismod interdum. Duis vitae sodales elit. Donec eu condimentum nisl.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="holder.js/400x200">
      <p>Aliquam faucibus vitae risus et tempus. Praesent ut ex at tortor congue condimentum. Praesent vel libero id augue ornare ultricies quis eu urna. Nulla et ornare risus. Duis volutpat, arcu a vulputate rhoncus, tortor leo lacinia turpis, sed cursus
        libero sapien quis neque. Curabitur dui nibh, convallis ut enim vitae, congue sollicitudin orci. Mauris pretium euismod interdum. Duis vitae sodales elit. Donec eu condimentum nisl.</p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. How will the image be pushed down by additional content?

Comment: I've updated the question. By additional content that can be added before the image. This is for a CMS that allows you to edit the whole page WYSIWYG like with AngularJS. The code above just shows the CSS problem.

Comment: Why don't you make the width like 99%? and min-width like 150px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can do this with some css.

I made the image 1px wide,
determined if the image position was above or below the sidebar
and then resize with jquery.

```
$(function(){
        var mainWidth = $('.main').width();
        var sidebarWidth = $('.sidebar').outerWidth();
        var sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').outerHeight();
        var imagePosition = $('.main > img').position().top;

        if(imagePosition < sidebarHeight){
          $('.main > img').css('width', mainWidth - sidebarWidth);
        }else{
          $('.main > img').css('width', 'auto');
        }
      });
```

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tLWXcLMloSgy527Gwzbz?p=preview

Comment: Using JS is fine for me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a separate div for your image. Put your image inside that div, make your float:none and play with margin properties. It is supposed to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand you correctly. But if you want the content of the `.sidebar`, to fill out the space, when the picture gets pushed down, you can just set the width of the `.sidebar` to `min-width` of 100px ?

like this: `min-width: 100px;`

[See here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wS08UPEPvTTVSFQUtHI0?p=preview)

Comment: Thats not what I try to do. I've updated my question with a hopefully better explanation of what is wanted.

Comment: Just for info, you img link holder.js are doing something to the picture so you cant resize it. Even when you set a style on the picture for 100px, it will still be 400px. I would recommend you use http://placehold.it/400x200 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with pure CSS here: [Can an image flow with text next to a floated element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487881/can-an-image-flow-with-text-next-to-a-floated-element/30491234#30491234)

You just need to wrap the image with an element set to `overflow: hidden`.