# Can an image flow with text next to a floated element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to find a simple solution to the following problem *without using JS*.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <p>[...]</p>
  <div class="mpu"></div>
  <img src="img-src">
  <p>[...]</p>
</div>
```

I have a container div with a class of `.wrap` that is filled with text. Inside this, I have a 300px square div with a class of `.mpu` that will display adverts. The ad unit appears between paragraphs of text and has the following style applied:

```
.mpu{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em -2em 1em 1em;
}
```

I also have a standard snippet in place for forcing images to resize with the viewport under a certain width:

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto!important;
}
```

So the `.mpu` ad unit is floated to the right but also sticks out 2em from the right-hand edge of the `.wrap` container because of the negative `margin-right`. The text inside the container flows neatly around the ad block, however, when an image tag is inserted beside the ad block, a white space is created as the image appears underneath it.

Is it possible to force images to flow around floated elements in the same way that text does? I'm aware that the ad unit has a float applied and has therefore been removed from the document flow so the image is being set to 100% of it's parent element's width i.e. `.wrap`'s width. Is there a workaround or ahem… a hack to override this behaviour?

Please refer to the following fiddle for a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7z0yypw1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7z0yypw1/2/ Something like that?

Comment: Img must be small? Or?..

Comment: Ah, should have mentioned: images will be added by editorial staff via a CMS and they can insert images anywhere in the document so the solution needs to work for images that _don't_ appear next to the ad unit (i.e. stretch to the full width of the container) as well as those that do.

Comment: So It must be small near the ad block and must be big otherwise. Right?

Comment: Float your image to the left. Then the text will wrap. I don't know how to explain this, but it works with me, using Chrome.
https://jsfiddle.net/7z0yypw1/3/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make an image resize dynamically next to a floating sidebar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840666/how-can-i-make-an-image-resize-dynamically-next-to-a-floating-sidebar)

Comment: I think perfect pure css solution is not possible. You can add `.mpu+img{max-width:50%;}` to your css, so images after .mpu will be 50% wide, others 100%. https://jsfiddle.net/7z0yypw1/4/

JS solution mentioned in comment by connexo above.

Comment: @designarti unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem because it removes the image from the document flow. Notice how the image in your example appears two paragraphs below where it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this: https://jsfiddle.net/7z0yypw1/6/

Wrap your img in a wrapper element, and give it a class imageWrapper. Then apply

```
.imageWrapper {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes!! I'm not even sure how this works but this is the solution, thank you! Can you explain why setting `overflow: hidden` on the parent element forces the image to resize?

Comment: The CSS 2.1 spec is pretty vague about this, and it seems to be something of a side-effect. Text wrapping around a float is extremely hard to implement for overflow values other than visible, so to avoid the problems, these cause the block element to form a new Block Formatting Context. These are defined to avoid floats - much like line boxes do - reducing in width to the remaining space. In fact, CSS 2.1 only suggests this as an option, it doesn't require browsers to do it, but seems that's the option all modern browsers have taken. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float

Answer (score 1):

I would make the image float with a nice margin around the image. Here is the code:

```
img {
   height:auto;
   max-width: 100%; /* set to what you want */
}

.newimageclass {
    float:left;
}
```

Hope that helps!